# Unicode character identification in grep

Tags: bash, unicode, cygwin

I found an extremely bizarre behavior and was wondering if anyone had any idea what could cause it. It is long to explain, so thanks for your patience.
I am running a bash script on a windows environment, invoked through cygwin.
In it, I basically want to find any lines in a file that have a character that is not found in a specific alphabet I am defining, simple enough.
Since I am using Unicode characters, I have set

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I have a file called "files.txt" which contains this:

```
$ cat files.txt
đđđ
üüü
```

I define my alphabet with normal characters as well as Unicode chars:

```
$ ALPHABET=$(printf %s {a..z} $(printf "\u0161") $(printf "\u010d"))
$ echo $ALPHABET
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzšč
$ grep -v "^[$ALPHABET ]*$" files.txt
đđđ
üüü
```

As expected. The problem comes particularly with the character "Ñ" (\u00d1) in combination with "đ" (\u0111):

```
$ ALPHABET=$(printf %s {a..z} $(printf "\u00d1") $(printf "\u0161") $(printf "\u010d"))
$ echo $ALPHABET
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÑšč
$ grep -v "^[$ALPHABET ]*$" files.txt
üüü
```

Interestingly, it only happens in some cases if other Unicode characters are added as well. The one constant is that "Ñ" must be there.

```
$ ALPHABET=$(printf %s {a..z} $(printf "\u00d1"))
$ echo $ALPHABET
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÑ
$ grep -v "^[$ALPHABET ]*$" files.txt
đđđ
üüü
$ ALPHABET=$(printf %s {a..z} $(printf "\u00d1") a $(printf "\u010d"))
$ echo $ALPHABET
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÑač
$ grep -v "^[$ALPHABET ]*$" files.txt
üüü
$ ALPHABET=$(printf %s {a..z} $(printf "\u010d") $(printf "\u00d1"))
$ echo $ALPHABET
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzčÑ
$ grep -v "^[$ALPHABET ]*$" files.txt
üüü
$ ALPHABET=$(printf %s {a..z} $(printf "\u010d") $(printf "\u010c"))
$ echo $ALPHABET
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzčČ
$ grep -v "^[$ALPHABET ]*$" files.txt
đđđ
üüü
$ ALPHABET=$(printf %s {a..z} $(printf "\u00d1") $(printf "\u00e1") $(printf "\u00c9"))
$ echo $ALPHABET
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÑáÉ
$ grep -v "^[$ALPHABET ]*$" files.txt
đđđ
üüü
```

I tried all sorts of combinations and ordering, and can't pinpoint exactly which type of combination determines that the grep decides that "đ" is in the pattern. The only thing I have found is that the "Ñ" must be present as well as some other arrangement of additional unicode characters, but I cannot figure out what this other arrangement must be.

Finally, if I execute these commands directly in the cygwin terminal, things work normally. This behavior only occurs if I call the execution of this script through Windows batch "C:\Tools\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe        %SCRIPT%".

Does anyone have any idea what may be happening? Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Try redirecting the output to a file. Does the problem still happen? It might be just the terminal's problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Same behavior outputting to a file. In fact, the grep was originally executed as "if grep -q ..." so the terminal output was never involved.

Comment: `Ñ` and `đ` both have identical second bytes under UTF-8 (`0x91`), so perhaps it's matching bytes rather than characters. Perhaps check the locale that it's executing under? Your example is fine for me when `LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"`, but fails the same as yours when `LC_ALL="C"`.

Comment: Thanks @nj_. You do have a good point that the two chars have the same second byte. However `š` and `á` also share the same second byte (`c5a1` and `c3a1`) and I haven't been able to reproduce the error with them. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: Where have you set LC_ALL?

Comment: @n.m. At the beginning of the script, right before the other lines shown. Without it `printf "\uXXXX"` just prints out the same literal 5 characters. LC_ALL set to some language and UTF-8 is required to convert those printfs to actual unicode chars, which is evidenced in the `echo $ALPHABET`.

Comment: I think you may have to export that variable. Not sure how it's working without that. Anyway what happens if you run the script from bash command line?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @n.m. for providing the right answer!
In effect, the LC_ALL had to be exported. Once I did, behavior was as expected and đ was not recognized as part of the pattern in all the different configurations I tried.
So instead of

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

use:

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Not sure why this is the case (since all commands run sequentially in the same terminal) but I guess if that's what makes it work, then go with it.
Thanks all for your help and suggestions, I realize the environment was not easy to reproduce.

Comment: As far as I can understand, the issue seems to be because printf is a native command of the bash shell, whereas grep is not and forks as a new process. As such, setting LC_ALL applies to the printf command (as evidenced when echoing ALPHABET), but does not apply to the grep unless it is exported.
Thanks to @n.m. again for suggesting to try this!